# Array.push() is not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, arrays

I'm pretty new to JS, but I can't get this to work on mobile.  Basically, i'm trying to push an id of a div into an array.  This works on every browser on my desktop and even in Safari when I go into developer mode for iOS.  However, when I check the console of Safari on my phone it appears that it's not pushing anything into the array.  It just keeps returning an empty array.

The `.getJSON` is working and it's listing all the divs, but it's not pushing anything into the array.  Any ideas? The console is just logging an empty array on every click.  The `clone()` is working as well.

```
$(".track").off("click").on("click", function() {
      if (queueList.length == 0) {
        queueList.push(this.id);
        playTrack(0);

      } else {
        queueList.push(this.id);
      }
      console.log(queueList);
      var cloned = $(this).clone();
      cloned.attr("id", queueList.length - 1);
      $("<span class='deleteQueue'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span>").prependTo(cloned);
      $(cloned).appendTo(".queueListDiv");
      deleteFromQueue();
    });
```

Comment: It is.  I have it set as a global variable.

Comment: How have you declared queueList